# Set-Cookie response and request

Tags: javascript, html, apache, http, cookies

When I make a HTTP request to get the index.html file from my Apache server using the browser, there is a proxy that redirects my traffic for login if a specific token is not present in the request headers. So it would make sense that the initial request would not have the token in the header and the proxy would then force redirect to login, after login I would be presented with the index.html file and also the relevant token in the response header.

So my question is the following:
If the server after login responds with the index.html file with the specific token in the response header, how can I make the browser automatically attach the token on all subsequent http requests?

At the moment after I get the index.html file back from the server, the browser will request all the fonts and libraries that is need to to load the app as referenced in the index.html file, but those requests do not contain the token in the request headers which in turn causes the browser to be redirected again for login. Such a viscous loop...

I am looking at making the proxy return the token in the header using 'Set-Cookie', but Chrome does not automatically add that cookie on all subsequent requests. Postman seems to add the header, but not Chrome. The cookie that I am setting must use the HttpOnly and Secure tags. So I am unable access it from JavaScript.

Please let me if there are any further questions.
Thanks in advance.

Kind regards
Francois

Comment: "I am looking at making the proxy return the token in the header using 'Set-Cookie', but Chrome does not automatically add that cookie on all subsequent requests." — It should do. Are you using different hostnames for different resources? Or redirecting to add or remove a www?

Comment: "The cookie that I am setting must use the HttpOnly and Secure tags" — Does your test environment use HTTPS?

Comment: I am not using any other hostnames, the whole app runs on a single node with one url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question.

This is how I tested. I created a docker container running Apache, which hosts an index.html, auth.html and login.html file. I then used the following httpd.conf setup using mod_rewrite to help with setting the cookies and testing for the cookies.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*X-TOKEN.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)login.html
RewriteRule (.*) "/login.html"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*X-TOKEN.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)login.html
RewriteRule (.*) "/auth.html"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)login.html
RewriteRule .* - [E=STATUS:1]

Header set Set-Cookie X-SBG-TOKEN=ThisIsMyToken;HttpOnly;Secure env=STATUS
```

Please excuse the horrible conditions :)

But what I have found is that on request I should not check for the `X-TOKEN` in the header, but I should check for it in the request cookies rather (this I still do not clearly understand, is the cookies sent with the request? How does the Apache server know about this cookie?). In this way I was able to check that the browser is indeed authenticated.

Thanks all who replied and helped!

Kind regards
Francois